# Strange An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker with generic repository

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, entity-framework-5

I am using EF 5.0 and have a generic context:

```
namespace ComTr.Web.BusinessLayer
{
    public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : ComTrBaseEntity //Use as base class to allow access to base entities properties like modified
    {
        internal ComTrContext Context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

        public GenericRepository()
        {
            Context = new ComTrContext();
            DbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetById(object id)
        {
            return DbSet.Find(id);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Edits the specified entity to update. Will attach entity to the context
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entityToUpdate">The entity to update.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual TEntity Edit(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            entityToUpdate.Modified = DateTime.Now;
            DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return entityToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I try to update a single value with following code:

```
var  ComBookingRespository = new ComBookingRespository();
comBooking= ComBookingRespository.GetById(adventureBookingId);

////Save Token in database
comBooking.PaymentToken = token;

ComBookingRespository.Edit(comBooking);
```

VS will stop at following line:

```
Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

with following error message:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

This is strange, because I have no other reference (as you can see the context is initiated newly).
How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is probably coming from the PaymentToken entity.

You have a token entity that you're attaching to your `adventureBooking`. Likely, you got that entity through a different generic repository, using the same logic - you created a context in that repository and retrieved the item. Since the token entity is attached to your `TokenRepository`, and your `adventureBooking` entity is attached to your `comBookingRepository` you have 2 different contexts.  Either disconnect your `token` entity from it's original repository, or overload your repository to be able to pass your context in, so your context is shared between your repos.

```
 public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
            DbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
```

Then in your code to create your repos:

```
var context = new new ComTrContext();
var  ComBookingRespository = new ComBookingRespository(context );
var  tokenRepository = new tokenRepository (context );
```

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake while editing the code for stackoverflow. In this case I have just one instance of my Repository that loads and edit the entity. However, the exception is still be thrown. However, when I change the code to it works. I cant see the difference between my respoistory method and the code below:                                      ComTrContext context = new ComTrContext();
                    comBooking = context.ComBooking.Find(adventureBookingId);
                    comBooking.PaymentToken = token;
                    context.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

Another instance of your context is tracking the entity in question.